# Wrap a paragraph around an image in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the paragraph to go around the image and wrap it so I don't waste space. My code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h1 class="display-4">Lorem ipsum</h1>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded-pill">התחל לכתוב</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.YrOgCeeTMGooIg3gpMz8qgHaHa%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=8172a3c985e7c4343b252d0ccaa06f7c36f146a5f6ce4f20fc7c801bf5ce2974&ipo=images" alt="Round Image" class="rounded-circle">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried having the image below the paragraph but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Please _tag_ your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 5 class `.float-start` for `float: left` and `.float-end` for `float: right`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<main class="fluid-container p-3">
  <header class="row">
    <h1 class="col p-2"><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/float/">Bootstrap 5 - Float</a></h1>
  </header>
  <section class="row">
    <article class="col p-2">
      <h2>"<code>.float-start</code>"</h2>
      <figure class="figure float-start col-4 p-2 pb-0 mb-0">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0m6612N/static.gif" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="Animated static">
        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">To <code>float: left</code> assign element "<code>.float-start</code>" class</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <p class="p-2">Endeavor soon recurred started lasting collecting wrote breeding absolute. Hastily placing county beauty innate placing demands eldest. Secure be manner lived even therefore death principle none behaved feebly giving off. Words passage education
        disposing understood concern improving impossible stairs rent father wandered rendered country service. Visitor sincerity explained post. </p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="row">
    <article class="col p-2">
      <h2>"<code>.float-end</code>"</h2>
      <figure class="figure float-end col-4 p-2 pb-0 mb-0">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0m6612N/static.gif" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="Animated static">
        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">To <code>float: right</code> assign element "<code>.float-end</code>" class</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <p class="p-2">Endeavor soon recurred started lasting collecting wrote breeding absolute. Hastily placing county beauty innate placing demands eldest. Secure be manner lived even therefore death principle none behaved feebly giving off. Words passage education
        disposing understood concern improving impossible stairs rent father wandered rendered country service. Visitor sincerity explained post. </p>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```